# Open link in new tab (dotnetbrowser winforms)

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol, dotnetbrowser

I using teamdev-dotnetbrowser in winforms. Also I using Tab Control. How to open link in new tab when clicked Ctrl + mouse left click or mouse wheel click.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new tab to the Tab Control like this using Ctrl + left mouse click.

```
private void tabPage1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                var newTabPage = new TabPage();
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Joseph.

Thank you for answer. I want to open the Ctrl + left click operation on the new tab when clicking on the links on the dotnetbrowser control. The code example you typed is not triggered on the browser